# How to transfer from one to another PC

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Have database and connected to it Apex application as interface for database. Now I wanna use this application with this database on another PC. How I can transfer it ?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Export the database for the current machine

Step 2:  Install the apex application and database in 2nd machine.

Step 3: import the database in 2nd machine and configure the apex application to use this database.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more question - can I export the Apex application on pc1 and import it on PC2 like I'm doing it with database?

Comment: You cannot export apex application to pc2.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the question, you don't "transfer" anything, but data.

Apex application is web-based, so all the "other PC" (let's call it "PC2") needs is a web browser. Those two computers have to be in the same network so that PC2 could run the application that resides in the PC1's database. Also, there has to be a server which will make that possible. The Apex built-in server (embedded PL/SQL gateway) is enough if there are a few users; otherwise, you'd rather install ORDS.

At the end, you'd share the application's URL with PC2's user and let it access data from the database that runs on PC1.